# Voice/speech recognition in Hololens that does not require gazing app window

Tags: uwp, speech-recognition, hololens, cortana

I am using this sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) from Microsoft for UWP platform. 
When the app runs in Hololens I need to be gazing at the 2D window for it to work.
If I don't, the application does not react at all to the voice commands.

However this is not what I want. I want to be able to look around the environment when giving a voice command. Similar to how you can give commands to Cortana. You do not have an app window in that case.
How can I achieve this?

Initialization:

```
private async Task InitializeRecognizer(Language recognizerLanguage)
        {
            if (speechRecognizer != null)
            {
                // cleanup prior to re-initializing this scenario.
                speechRecognizer.StateChanged -= SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;
                speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed -= ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
                speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated -= ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

                this.speechRecognizer.Dispose();
                this.speechRecognizer = null;
            }

            try
            {
                this.speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(recognizerLanguage);
                speechRecognizer.StateChanged += SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

                // add list constaints here



                SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
                if (result.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
                {
                    rootPage.NotifyUser( "Unable to compile grammar.",NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
                    speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if ((uint)ex.HResult == HResultRecognizerNotFound)
                {
                    rootPage.NotifyUser( "Speech Language pack for selected language not installed.",NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }

        }
```

Listening method

```
public async void StartListening()
        {
            if (isListening == false)
            {
                // The recognizer can only start listening in a continuous fashion if the recognizer is currently idle.
                // This prevents an exception from occurring.
                if (speechRecognizer.State == SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
                        isListening = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isListening = false;
                if (speechRecognizer.State != SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Cancelling recognition prevents any currently recognized speech from
                        // generating a ResultGenerated event. StopAsync() will allow the final session to 
                        // complete.
                        await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.CancelAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12630/hololens-cortana-on-hololens says [Some Cortana features you're used to from Windows on your PC or phone (for example, reminders and notifications) aren't supported in Microsoft HoloLens Development Edition. Cortana on HoloLens is English only, and the Cortana experience may vary among regions.]  Where are you?